# Constructor parameters for controllers without a DI container for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have any code examples on how to create controllers that have parameters other than using a Dependency Injection Container?

I see plenty of samples with using containers like StructureMap, but nothing if you wanted to pass in the dependency class yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use poor-man's dependency injection:

```
public ProductController() : this( new Foo() )
{
  //the framework calls this
}

public ProductController(IFoo foo)
{
  _foo = foo;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

One way is to create a ControllerFactory:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(
        RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return [construct your controller here] ;
    }
}
```

Then, in Global.asax.cs:

```
    private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
            new MyNamespace.MyControllerFactory());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an IModelBinder that spins up an instance from a factory - or, yes, the container.  =)