# Server Error in '/' Application. No parameterles constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

I'm getting a `No parameterles constructor defined for this object` error in my `HomeController.cs`. According to [ASP.NET MVC: No parameterless constructor defined for this object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355475/651779) I have to make sure that my `ActionResults` don't have a parameter. But my HomeController ActionResult doesn't have a parameter:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// injected settings
    /// </summary>
    private ISettings settings;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HomeController"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="settings">The settings.</param>
    public HomeController(ISettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default index page
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>redirects to the default application home page</returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = settings.Application, master = "default" });
    }
}
```

How can I find out where the error comes from?

Full stacktrace:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +67

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Web.Lifescience.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970356
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't connected with `ActionResult`. Your `HomeController` doesn't have parameterless constructor.
If you use controller's constructor with parameters, you should create your [custom controller factory](http://keyvan.io/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc) or use dependency injection: [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122273/constructor-parameters-for-controllers-without-a-di-container-for-asp-net-mvc) or with IoC-container according to your logic.

Comment: Adding         public HomeController() : this(new ISettings())
        {
        } as suggested by the manually post gives doesn't work because I can't create an instance of an abstract class or interface (ISettings)

Comment: @Niek de Klein, of course you should pass some implementation of `ISettings`. What do you pass as a parameter in your program?

Comment: I edited it in my post, the code is from HomeController instead of what I had before.

Comment: @Niek de Klein, as far as I understood, you're trying to use some IoC-container (Autofac, Ninject, Windsor Castle, Unity or something). When you configure it correctly, it will automatically resolve `ISettings` as some class, that implements it.