# No parameterless constructor defined for this object in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
using Michell.ClaimsAuditAdmin.Models;
using Mitchell.ClaimsAuditAdmin.Repositories;
using Mitchell.ClaimsAuditAdmin.Web.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mitchell.ClaimsAuditAdmin.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ClaimAuditAdminController : Controller
    {  
       private readonly IClaimsAuditAdminRepository claimAuditAdminRepository;


       public ClaimAuditAdminController(IClaimsAuditAdminRepository claimAuditAdminRepository)
       {
           this.claimAuditAdminRepository = claimAuditAdminRepository;
       }

         public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("SearchResultTest");
        }

        public ActionResult TestView()
        {
            return View("TestView");
        }


        public ViewResult DisplayClaimAuditView()
        {
           return View("_ClaimAuditAdminView");
        }

        public ActionResult SearchResultTest()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ClaimAuditReviewFilter()
        {
            //ClaimAuditModel objClaimAudit = new ClaimAuditModel();
            //objClaimAudit.ClaimAudit_ID = 1;
            //objClaimAudit.ClaimAudit_Name = "Claim1";
            //objClaimAudit.FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            //objClaimAudit.FromDate = DateTime.Now;
            return PartialView("_ClaimAuditAdminView");
        }



    }
}
```

I know this question has  been asked many times,but after reading all those SO similar questions i am not able to track my error.I have put the debugger in My controller's Constructor(ClaimAuditAdminController) but debugger doesn't goes there.
My **Route.Config** is

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ClaimAuditAdmin", action = "DisplayClaimAuditView", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

and the screen shot of my error is

> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for this object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'Mitchell.ClaimsAuditAdmin.Web.Controllers.ClaimAuditAdminController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +179
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +74
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +197    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929 
>           }

Comment: Had this same problem, but it turned out that I'd forgotten to call my DI container's `Initialize()` method due to my haste in copying and pasting my `SimpleInjectorInitializer` class. Also had to fix the `namespace`. (D'OH!)

Hopefully this will help someone here in the future. :)

Comment: I solved this error based on the answer this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605540/109850)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

activator trying to create ur controller with parametrless constructor. but while your controller constructor has parameter

```
public ClaimAuditAdminController(IClaimsAuditAdminRepository claimAuditAdminRepository) <--this place
   {
       this.claimAuditAdminRepository = claimAuditAdminRepository;
   }
```

the exception occurs.
Try to remove param from constructor or try override the DefaultControllerFactory
and create controller with parameter.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122273/constructor-parameters-for-controllers-without-a-di-container-for-asp-net-mvc)