# MVC:No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Server Error in '/' Application.
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.How can I resolve this issue.
I created one folder in that created interface ICompanyService and class    CompanyService.

Controller:

```
         public class HomeController : Controller
         {
               private ICompanyService icompanyService;
               public HomeController(ICompanyService icompanyService)
              {
                 this.icompanyService = icompanyService;
               }
                public ActionResult Index()
              {     
                 ViewBag.CompanyName = this.icompanyService.GetCompany();
                return View();
              }
         }
```

ICompanyService:

```
                 public interface ICompanyService
                {
                 string GetCompany();
                }
```

CompanyService:

```
                   public class CompanyService
                   {
                      public string GetCompany()
                     {
                         return "Msc";
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: Where abouts is this error thrown?

Comment: it is throwing run time exception No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Comment: Surely it'll get thrown on a line though

Comment: it is not showing error line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include below constructor to your controller,

```
        public HomeController() : this(new CompanyService())
            {
            }
```

So your entire controller code looks like below,

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ICompanyService icompanyService;

    public HomeController() : this(new CompanyService())
    {
    }
    public HomeController(ICompanyService icompanyService)
    {
        this.icompanyService = icompanyService;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CompanyName = this.icompanyService.GetCompany();

        return View();
    }
}
```

This will solve your issue.

Happy coding!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> CompanyService Class Should Inherits From ICompanyService Interface.
>        Please Study About Dependency Injection In .NET .

```
 public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
                   {
                      public string GetCompany()
                     {
                         return "Msc";
                     }
                   }
```

Comment: still it is throwing same issue

Comment: Beacuse You Don't Use Dependency Injection In Project.
Configure Like The 'Auto Fac' Or 'Ninject' Or 'Unity' In Project.
Constructor Controller By Defualt Don't Have Parameter.

Comment: I hope this link will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122273/constructor-parameters-for-controllers-without-a-di-container-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

@ravi please use dependency injection, so what service will automatically initialize your service constructor without defined constructor logic, the dependency inject handle and initialize you service object. don't worry about initialization.

below i have mention the link for IoC and i hope your issue will resolve soon.
https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet/blob/master/README.md#ioc